# using linux cmds to match a list names against a bunch of files

Tags: linux, file, command-line, matching

I have a slight problem with matching file names.

I have one text file that contains some 160 names. I have a folder with 2000+ files. and some of them contains these 160 names. I am looking for a grep cmd that can take each name in the text file and try to match it to the contents of the folder.

I am trying to do this in perl, or just straight forward linux cmds, but neither has worked out very well for me because I am not familiar with either of them.

so for example: the text file contains

```
abc acc eee fff
```

and the folder will have abcXXX, accXXX, eeeXXX and fffXXX

I need to sort through the list and find out which one were missing.

thx
Davy

Answer (score 1):

If you search in the content of the files :

```
#!/bin/sh  
for i in `cat files`
do
    grep -R $i folder --color
done
```

and if you search in the filename of the files :

```
#!/bin/sh 
for i in `cat files`
do
find . -name $i*
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in $(< list); 
do 
   [ ! -f ${file}xxx ] && echo "x: " ${file}xxx
done
```

`list` is the file, containing the list of filenames "abc acc ...".
`<` is redirection - so we read from the file 'list', the same as `$(cat list)`. If the file isn't named 'list', just replace the name.
`file` is declared in that statement and iteratively bound to all those entries in 'list'. Later it is used as ${file}.
`[ ! -f ${file}xxx ]` is a test, whether a -f(ile) exists, for abc it searchs for a file abcxxx.
But ! negates the search, so if no such file exists, then `echo ...` is called. "x: " is just a debug relict.

We can improve that part:

```
for file in $(< list); 
do 
   [ -f ${file}xxx ] || echo ${file}xxx
done
```

instead of 'NOT x AND y' we can write 'x OR y' - the meaning is the same, just shorter: the file does exist or echo its name.

|| is short-circuit OR.

Comment: could you please clarify the cmds?  is the file a variable? and what about list? are they both variables I would have to declare?

Comment: thx for the clarification, I am trying to run the code now but it keeps telling me that "Missing $ on loop variable at toronto160_match_aginst_file.pl line 1". Also, should it be a for loop or foreach loop?

Comment: `...against_file.pl`? Are we talking about Perl? What I wrote is shellcode, 'Bash', to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

If you can arrange for the text file to have each name on a separate line then the following command will do what you need:

```
ls myfolder | grep -f mytextfile
```

One way to get each name on a separate line in the text file would be to edit a copy in `vi` and issue the commands:

```
:%s/ /^V^M/g
:wq
```

(`^V^M` means type "control-v" then "control-m")

Comment: hi perry, thx for the reply, I tried your cmd and it says -f is an illegal option for grep.

Comment: the -f option isn't working, it says it is an illegal option. could I replace it with ack and still achieve the same result?

Comment: What variety of Linux are you using?  "-f" has been a grep option for a very long time!

Comment: I have no idea, i think whoever did the server might have disabled it.

Comment: older versions of unix had a suite of grep cmds; grep, egrep and fgrep (maybe 1 or 2 more), that were replaced by GNU grep with options, i.e. grep -E and grep -? hmm, guessing -F. So if grep -f doesn't work, try fgrep -f srchTargfile. Note fgrep -f .. will not process any regexps in srchtargFiile. @Davy: All of these are good answers, please upvote them and when you get 15 rep points, please accept one as the your working answers. Good luck.